# How to use the result from a <script> function and assign it to style in html [for top & left positioning]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since CSS can't handle sine or cosine calculations, I am using `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` inside a `<script>` element in my HTML.  I'm trying to use the results to position `left` and `top`.   There just doesn't seem to be an easy solution.  My code below works, but I can't use the results in a style element to position `left` or `top`.

```html
<p id="GetHeight"></p>
<script>
    function myCosFunction(b, angle) {
        return Math.cos(angle*Math.PI / 180)*b;
    }
    document.getElementById("GetHeight").innerHTML = myCosFunction(240, 18);
</script>
```

Comment: check out my answer also, perhaps it could heIp

Answer (score 1):

You can use positioning like that

For apply `left` CSS in `GetHeight` id

```
document.getElementById("GetHeight").style.left = myCosFunction(240, 18);
```

same as for `top`

```
document.getElementById("GetHeight").style.top = myCosFunction(240, 18);
```

Comment: Nisharg Shah, wow that was quick...appreciate it.  I actually did try this, but was not able to figure out where to insert it.  Currently it is being positioned from css.. see below  .. #Robotics {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  top: calc((290px - 240px) - (76.5px / 2));
  left: calc((1000px / 2) - (56.2px / 2));
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}  then I

Comment: i don't get it your point, explain in brief and what you mean by `where to insert it`

Comment: Nisharg Shah,  I have a 240px Radius circle that I calculated 20 points [18 degrees apart] along the circle and I have created 20 boxes with a list in each of them and need to locate each of these boxes [centered at each point] at the 18 degrees location of the circle.   I used script to get the points along the circle, but can't figure out how to position the boxes with the results of the script function. I want to do this automated because the circle changes from time to time.

Comment: you have to mention this in question and for that you need to show your code

Answer (score 1):

The other easy way to use the value from `script` in `CSS` is giving the `innerHTML` to `style` element using `JS` as follows;

```js
var size=parseInt(myCosFunction(80, 7));
document.getElementById('style').innerHTML="#box{margin-top:"+
                                            size+"px;margin-left:"+ 
                                   size+"px;height:100px;width:100px;background:red}";
function myCosFunction(b, angle) {
  return Math.cos(angle*Math.PI / 180)*b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style id="style">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        Me
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js_function.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Note:** I have converted the value to int because the value used in `CSS` properties should be discrete.

***Update:***

If you want to get `margin-top` and `margin-left` of box form a sin function then you can simply call the function for two times using two variables that is X and Y. Then you can change the parameters of calling function to get different values of X and Y;

```js
var Y=parseInt(mySinFunction(280, 7));
var X=parseInt(mySinFunction(300, 7));
document.getElementById('style').innerHTML="#box{margin-top:"+
                                            Y+"px;margin-left:"+ 
                                   X+"px;height:100px;width:100px;background:red}";
function myCosFunction(b, angle) {
  return Math.cos(angle*Math.PI / 180)*b;
}
function mySinFunction(b, angle) {
    return Math.sin(angle*Math.PI / 180)*b;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style id="style">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        Me
    </div>
</body>
<script src="sin_fun.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: If there is any confusion in my ans then you can ask in the comment

Comment: I took what you have done, which is very close to what I am trying to do.   How can I  show the box at 22 locations on the 265 Radius circle using your code above.

Comment: Just posted the attempted code to show more detail.

Comment: how would you add coordinates X and Y value [sin] to this and position the box?

Comment: i don't exactly understand that what output you want to achieve. But if you want to get X and Y coordinates of the above box from sin. Then you can use `Math.sin()` instead if `Math.cos()`. And you can call this function for two times for setting the values of X and Y. After that you can use X and Y to position the box.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, could you add that to the script above?  I'm having troubles seeing exactly how that would look.

Comment: @JayReese I updated the answer. If it solves you problem then please up-vote and accept my answer. But if there is any problem in the answer then you can ask again in the comment.

Comment: This works great, Thanks for the help.  I do see that the var X=parseInt(mySinFunction(300, 7)); should be myCosFunction... I'm sure that is just from a copy/paste.

Comment: @JayReese please up-vote and accept my answer if your problem is solved

Comment: I'm pretty new here as you can tell... please advise how to up vote?

Comment: @JayReese here is an image that shows how you can [up-vote and accept the answer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A_aTMwRDwYXFa-xcnXVt2g0kTIiRgmrR/view?usp=sharing)